# How do you find and extract information from a table of a website?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, nodes, html-agility-pack

I am very new to C# and in specific HtmlAgilityPack, and I am having trouble getting information from websites. For example I want to get the images url from the table of the website:
[Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-rs/004.shtml)

From the website I am trying to find and extract the following:

[image: Link to picture]

```
 string s = "http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-rs/005.shtml";

        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(s);

        //HtmlNodeCollection items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='question-hyperlink']");
        HtmlNodeCollection items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr//td//div//table//tbody//tr//td//img");
        foreach (HtmlNode item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.OuterHtml);
            MessageBox.Show(item.OuterHtml);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I am fairly certain I am way off the ball, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you needing to do when you say extract? The table obviously is just going to contain the path to the image, so are you just looking to get the URL to image or actually download and save a copy of each image locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only hope that the developer doesn't like to update the source code often.

```
var item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table//tr//tr//td//div//tr//img");
string imageSrc = item.GetAttributeValue("src", "");
Console.WriteLine(imageSrc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, may I ask what "[0]" represents? I have played around with it a little but I don't quite understand it.

Comment: The [0] returns the first item in the array since there are more than one image that matches that format.